# Display messages according timer tick in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, timer

Suppose I have meeting 31/1/2011 9.30 and when current time becomes 31/1/2011 9.30 it displays a message: "You have a meeting". How can I do this with VB.NET?

Comment: I provided a [pretty comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862156/how-can-i-periodically-ping-a-server-to-determine-if-it-is-available-from-a-vb-ne/4862519#4862519) to a similar question yesterday. You should be able to extrapolate the solution to your problem using the explanation I've given there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this with the windows based project then add the timer in you form.

And set the fix time for the timer tick say 5 minutes or 10 minutes.

Then in tick event check is there any event has to occur and display the message for that event.

If you are doing this in Web based application.

Then code for application_start in global.asax and create a new thred which check the event to occur at regular interval of time.

Comment: its ok...its a windows based application.....suppose i want display mesg on 31/1/2011 9.30....how to give condition in tick event and what should be the interval....consider today as 30/1/2011 10.00

Comment: Interval must be the time you consider to be safe to show the message.. might be 1 sec. And in that event you have to check in database whether is there any event running out or not... if you got that event then fire the message.

Comment: an event will be raise in every tick. Set the tick time for every minute, and then, in the event code, check the time comparing it with datetime.now and do stuff if proceed.